# From AWS connect to external oracle database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an nodejs application deployed in aws, from nodejs application I want to connect to an external oracle database which is running on a different server, can anybody please tell me the steps to connect to external oracle database or please share any document that tell the steps to connect to oracle database from nodejs application deployed in aws.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You tagged both EC2 and Lambda, which one are you using? Is the database accessible from the Internet?

Comment: Oracle provides a getting started guide -  https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#getstarted on how to user their driver to connect and perform some basic operations. As for connecting to an external database - it depends where it is on the network/internet. Thats more a super user or server fault question - but you will need to describe the hosting of the external oracle server for anyone to help you. You will likely need to change AWS Security groups, software firewalls etc and possibly do VPC peering (within AWS) or VPN depending how far/security requirements

Comment: Hi Mark, I am using lambda, the oracle db is on cloud.   I am seeing the following error in the aws cloud watch logs :    2022-05-11T12:37:48.537Z 128ecfd0-22c3-4314-bf04-cc322a9a4edb INFO Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a VPC and add a VPC endpoint that points to the host of your external Database, depending on your infra this might be done without VPC using peering connection but not recommended.